# How to fix the unreachable code in C? I can't print the user's input

Tags: c

When I run my code, it shown unreachable code. It doesn't effect what I want to print. But I just can't print the input from the user.

I tried to define CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS also can't help

I expect to print the name, SID, block, total payable, but it didn't print anything out. It will only print the Name, SID, and so on but not the input user key in.

```
if(GDR==1 && type==3){
        room_rate=150;
        strcpy(r[i].block, "A3");
        printf("\nHow many weeks of room booking?\n");
        scanf("%i",&R_week);

        printf("\nName\t\t:");
        scanf("%s",r[i].name);
        printf("Student ID\t :");
        scanf("%s",r[i].SID);
        printf("Type\t\t  :%s\n",rm[i].type);
        r[i].room=r[i].room+1;
        A3_no=1+A3_no;

        printf("\nDo you want to change your room type?\n1 Yes\n2 No\n3 Main Menu\nPlease enter your option:");
        scanf("%i",&change);
        if(change==1){
            Room_Type();
            Details();
            goto start;}
        if(change==2){
Meal2:
            printf("\nDo you want to subscribe for Meal?\n1 Yes\n2 No\nPlease enter your option:");
            scanf("%i",&A1_Meal);
            if(A1_Meal==1){
                printf("\n\nSorry, this service is not available for subscription. Thank you.\n");
                goto Gym2;}
            if(A1_Meal ==2){
                goto Gym2;}
            else{
                goto Meal2;}

Gym2:
            printf("\nDo you want to subscribe for Gym?\n1 Yes\n2 No\nPlease enter your option:");
            scanf("%i",&A1_Gym);
            if(A1_Gym==1){
                printf("\nSorry, this service is not available for subscription. Thank you\n");
                goto Internet2;}
            if(A1_Gym==2){
                goto Internet2;}
            else{
                goto Gym2;}
Internet2:
            printf("\nDo you want to subscribe for Internet?\n1 Yes\n2 No\nPlease enter your option:");
            scanf("%i",&A1_Internet);
            if(A1_Internet==1){
                Internet_rate=15;
                printf("\nHow many weeks of subscription?\n");
                scanf("%i",&I_week);
                goto Laundry2;}
            if(A1_Internet==2){
                Internet_rate=15;
                I_week=0;
                goto Laundry2;}
            else{
                goto Internet2;}
Laundry2:
            printf("\nDo you want to subscribe for Laundry?\n1 Yes\n2 No\nPlease enter your option:");
            scanf("%i",&A1_Laundry);
            if(A1_Laundry==1){
                Laundry_rate=20;
                printf("\nHow many weeks of subscription?\n");
                scanf("%i",&L_week);

                room_total= room_rate * R_week;
                L_total = Laundry_rate * L_week;
                I_total = Internet_rate * I_week;
                r[i].total = room_total + I_total+L_total;
                printf("\n============== Payment Details ===============\n");
                printf("\nWeekly rate for the room\t: RM%i\n%i weeks of subscription\t\t: RM%i\nWeekly rate for the laundry\t: RM%i\n%i weeks of subscription\t\t: RM%i\nWeekly rate for the Internet\t: RM%i\n%i weeks of subscription\t\t: RM%i\n\nTotal amount payable is RM%i.\n",room_rate, R_week, room_total, Laundry_rate,L_week,L_total,Internet_rate,I_week,I_total,r[i].total);
                goto Pay;}
            if(A1_Laundry==2){
                Laundry_rate=20;
                L_week=0;
                room_total= room_rate * R_week;
                L_total = Laundry_rate * L_week;
                I_total = Internet_rate * I_week;
                r[i].total = room_total + I_total+L_total;
                printf("\n============== Payment Details ===============\n");
                printf("\nWeekly rate for the room\t: RM%i\n%i weeks of subscription\t\t: RM%i\nWeekly rate for the laundry\t: RM%i\n%i weeks of subscription\t\t: RM%i\nWeekly rate for the Internet\t: RM%i\n%i weeks of subscription\t\t: RM%i\n\nTotal amount payable is RM%i.\n",room_rate, R_week, room_total, Laundry_rate,L_week,L_total,Internet_rate,I_week,I_total,r[i].total);
                goto Pay;}
            else{
                goto Laundry2;}
Pay2:
            printf("==============================================\n");
            printf("\nDo you want to cancel booking or proceed to make payment?\n1 Make Payment\n2 Cancel Booking\nPlease enter your option:");
            scanf("%i",&cancel);
            if(cancel==1){
                printf("\nDo you want to make payment now or later by cash?\n1 Now\n2 Cash\nPlease enter your option:");
                scanf("%i",&pay);
                if(pay==1){
                    strcpy(r[i].PS, "Paid");
                    printf("\nPlease deposit your money in the slot provided.\nMaximum cash per deposit is 100 pieces of any combined denominations.\n");
                    printf("Thank you for your payment.\n\n");
                    goto Printing_2;
                    continue;}
                if(pay==2){
                    strcpy(r[i].PS, "Pending");
                    printf("Please proceed to counter 1. Payment must be made within 7 days. Thank you.\n\n");
                    goto Printing_2;}
                else{
                    goto Pay2;
                    break;}}
            if(cancel==2){
                goto Main_Menu;}
            else{
                goto Pay2;}
Printing_2:
            printf("\n============== Hosteler Details ===============\n");
            printf("Name\t\t: %s\nStudent ID\t: %s\nGender\t\t: %s\nBlock\t\t: %s\nRoom Number\t: %i\nType\t\t: %s\nTotal payable\t: RM%i\nPayment Status\t: %s",r[i].name,r[i].SID,rm[i].Gender,r[i].block,A3_no,rm[i].type,r[i].total,r[i].PS);
            printf("\n============================================\n");}

        if(change==3){
            goto Main_Menu;}
        else{
            goto Main_Menu;}}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is *unreachable?*  Maybe the proper conditions didn't exist for that code to be reached.

Comment: Did the compiler warn that the code is unreachable or did you determine that by some other means. And where's the code?

Comment: The same code in other loop function well, I don't know why in the others, no.

Comment: Edit the code into your question.  It's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: I'm using JetBrains Clion 2019.1.4. It shows unreachable code from Pay2 to the end of Printing

Comment: I notice that continue statment will never reach counse of the goto printing_2

Comment: I have one room with two bed, and I want to increase the room number only when there is  two people book the room with the same room number. Anyone has any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is right your code after `Pay2` is unreachable as its above `laundary2` ends with `if condition` that make your code run to `pay` or back to `laundary2` in any case. `Pay2` isn't reached in any case in your code and I haven't seen any line that made a call of jumping to `Pay2`.

Your code has some logical error, as we don't know the application and full code so we can't help further.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't notice that I should put Pay2 instead of Pay. The problem is solved. Thank you so much

Comment: @SofhinWong Please [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you're satisfied.